# Force 2.0 finds error in a fortran 95 program but the program has correct syntax

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I downloaded `Force 2.0` for fortran 95.

When I write a program, even though the source code is correct - I checked it in my university lab - I got many errors.

This is my code:

```
program sum1
implicit none
integer :: a , b , sum
print*, 'Give a and b'
read*, a, b
sum = a+b
print *, 'sum=' , sum
pause
end program sum1
```

The errors I get are:

```
Line 3: parse error, unexpected ':', expecting Do or IF or SELECTCASE
Line 4: Unknown base for typeless constant -- octal assumed
Line 4: Badly formed typeless constant
Line 8: Illegal character
```

Comment: @VladimirF Yes you are right! I revisited my question.

Comment: What is the name of source file? Through which command is the compiler run?

Comment: @VladimirF The name of the source file is `ex1.f95`. I compile the program through `Force 2.0` IDE using the default command. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: You think this is a fixed format vs free format issue?

Comment: @ja72 I don't know. I run the same program in my lab at the university and it's working.

Comment: Try to put everything on column 7 and beyond

Comment: @ja72 I tried and I got 2 errors: `Line 3: symbol redeclared sum` and `Line 6: numeric or character quantity expected: prog SUM`. I got it, I have program name and a variable using the same name.

Comment: @ja72 By changing the name of the program I still get two errors: `Line 1: file format not recognized; treating as linker script` and `Line 1:  parse error`.

Comment: Try renaming the file to have a .f90 file type. .f95 is an abomination. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/11/doctor-fortran-in-source-form-just-wants-to-be-free

Comment: Use `.f`, `.for` or `.f77` for fixed format and `.f90` or `.f08` for free format files. The compiler may have some settings on how to treat each file extension.

Comment: Don't use .f77 or .f08. .f or .for for fixed-form, .f90 for free-form. Anything else and the compiler may not recognize it.

Comment: where did you get a f95 version of force?

Comment: @agentp I don't remember. Finally I downloaded  `Force209G95Setup.exe` from here: http://force.lepsch.com/2009/05/downloads.html and it's working properly.